# Converting incorrectly encoded Chinese characters in MySQL to UTF-8

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8, latin1

I have a large MySQL table filled with Chinese characters in an incorrect encoding. I believe they were supposed to be encoded in latin1 (iso-8859-1), but I just can't find a way to get the Chinese characters from the contents of the database rows.

Converting between latin1 and utf8 doesn't help - the fields remain unchanged. I've tried re-importing the database with various encodings - always the same results.

Some examples of the current contents and what they should be:

- `æƒ¨äº‹` should be `惨事`
- `ä`¸ should be `不`
- `æœ€` should be `最`

I've also tried using Python to try and 'decode' the contents, but again without success. I've tried various combinations of this:

```
databasefield.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')
```

But I can't get anything like that to work either.

Sorry for asking such a vague question, but I just don't know how to continue trying to figure this out!

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: Your *first* example has extra characters *between* the latin1 bytes that make up the UTF-8 for the two correct glyphs. `u'惨事'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')` results in `æ¨äº`..

Comment: Ah, some bytes are not printable, so `u'\xe6\x83\xa8\xe4\xba\x8b'` is the output and then it looks like a Windows codepage instead. I think I found your solution, let me verify.

Comment: You may want to give us the *representation* of these values. What does `repr(databasefield)` give you for each of these? We may be looking at what your Windows codepage thinks the bytes are, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at UTF-8 decoded as [Windows codepage 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead:

```
>>> print u'惨事'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252')
æƒ¨äº‹
>>> print u'最'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252')
æœ€
```

Fixing this requires going the other way:

```
>>> print u'æƒ¨äº‹'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
惨事
>>> print u'æœ€'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
最
```

There may have been some *loss* there though, as the UTF-8 encoding for `不` uses a codepoint not supported by 1252:

```
>>> u'不'.encode('utf8')
'\xe4\xb8\x8d'
>>> print u'不'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 2: character maps to <undefined>
```

There are several other Windows codepage candidates that can be tried here though; [1254](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254) would result in similar output, for example, with only minor differences.